# AWS Redshift maximums

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have recently started exploring Amazon redshift database. However I am not able to find the below database maximum parameters anywhere in the documentations .

**Parameters**

```
Columns       Maximum per table or view 
Names         Maximum length of database and column names
Characters    Maximum number of characters in a char/varchar field
Connections   Maximum connections to the server
concurency    Maximm number of concurrent users
Row size      Maximum row size
DISTKEY       Maximum per table
SORTKEY       Maximuum per table(compound/interval)
Cluster size  Maximum cluster size(in terms of compressed datasize)
```

Would be of great help if anyone can provide the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connection limits, concurrency limits and naming contraints are detailed here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html

Currently there is a max of 500 connections and 50 concurrency per cluster.

You can have one DISTKEY per table, more details here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html

Interleaved sort keys are limited to eight columns:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data.html

Maximum length of character data types:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

Cluster size is determined by the number and type of nodes in the cluster. In terms of storage the current maximum possible is 128 x ds2.8xlarge nodes, for a max storage of 2 Petabytes:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html

With recent RA3 node type (ra3.16xlarge) you can go up to 8PB

Answer (score 0):

500 is maximun for Query Editor not the real maximum DB Connections.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).